# How to get row count for jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, count, row

I would like to know how to get row count for jqGrid. I'm using `rowNum: -1` so it displays all the rows. I tried using:

```
parseInt($("#grid").getGridParam("records"), 10)
```

But it always returns `0`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 37):

Try:

```
$("#grid").getGridParam("reccount")
```

from the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> **reccount** (*integer*):
>
> Readonly property. Returns the exact number of rows in the grid

---

Note also that, as Mike commented, you need to use the `getGridParam` method with the `records` option to retrieve a count of all the rows if you are using pagination.

Comment: Note that if you have paging turned on in your jqGrid, this function will just return the number of rows shown *on this page*.  To get the full row count, use the 'getGridParam' function, shown in one of the other answers.

Comment: @MikeGledhill - Thanks, I updated this answer to include `records` since none of the other answers explain why that works. Note the op was not using pagination, but a lot of people reading this could be...

Answer (score 17):

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried reccount and I got zero but the following worked for me.

```
<div>Total subscriber count: <div id="count" style="display: inline;"></div></div>

<br />

<div>
    <table id="grid"></table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            //Other stuff removed for brevity
            gridComplete: function () {
                $('#count').html($('#grid').getGridParam('records'));
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill and don't know if there's a better way, but this works for me:

```
$("#grid").getRowData().length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="g9" onclick="alert(jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam','records'));">Get number of records in Grid</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i get the grid data to array and then use the array length function to get the array length. It is equal for the number of record in the jqgrid.

```
//get the grid data to array      
var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
//  get the length of the array on array.length using javascript funcation
alert('' + rows.length);
```