# Jqgrid multiselect selected rows count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm using Jqgrid by multiselect option. I want to get selected rows count on Jqgrid .

I tried that but no luck...

```
var count = jQuery('#grid').length;
    if (count > 5)
    alert('The Selected Rows More Than 5')
```

Comment: duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587817/how-to-get-row-count-for-jqgrid  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566617/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-jqgrid

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of those posted by diEcho. This question is specific to having the multiselect option turned on (multiselect: true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just get the length of the array [selarrrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

```
var selRowIds = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
alert ('The number of selected rows: ' + selRowIds.length);
```

Comment: @Oleg, wont this would also count empty field as well when multiselect is set to true `<input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="cb_grid" role="checkbox">` making total of `selRowIds + 1`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: some time before you posted questions about problems with multiselect count, but if I remind me correctly, the problem existed only in combination with some old version of jQuery. I had no demo where I could reproduce the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/62/ or http://jsfiddle.net/aagxejj5/61/ in comments to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31761607/315935). The demos displays **correct** value in all my tests. Which problem exactly you have now?

Comment: @Oleg the comment was out of curiosity, possibly my issue could be with older versions. Thanks again for your prompt response..:)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Place a link anywhere you want

```
<a href="/" id="displayNoSelectedRows">Click me!</a>
```

and now simply register the callback function

```
$("#displayNoSelectedRows").click(function() {
    var no = $("input[id^='jqg_gridid_']:checked").length;
    alert(no);
    return false;
});
```

for this link, where `gridid` is the table's id. With the knowledge of how the checkboxes are named (or better the way the ids are assigned) this is a possible way to get the number of selected checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood you. I thought you wanted to count the number of selected rows when using the multiselect option.